# SSL Certificate on Weblogic 10.3

Tags: ssl-certificate

Scenarion:
I`m using Weblogic 10.3 as my webserver, I have successfully configure ssl using port 443, infact I can access it via https.

Now, I want to buy a certificate (e.g verisign, thwarte, etc...), the thing is, this will require me to generate a CSR.

My problem is I wasnt able to generate it, or maybe should I say I dont know how.

Please help! can anyone send me a step by step procedure on how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Eric Gako

Answer (score 1):

Hi its my understanding that weblogic uses the java ketsore/keytool technology in which case:

Generate the store and kepair

keytool -genkey -alias %ALIAS% -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024 -dname %DNAME% -keypass  %KPASS% -keystore %KSTORE% -storepass %STOREPASS%

Output PKCS10 request

keytool -certreq -alias %ALIAS% -keystore %KSTORE% -storepass %STOREPASS% -keypass %KPASS% -file certrequestfilepkcs10

Mark Sutton
http://www.blacktipconsulting.com